# Dynamic 'uib-tooltip-html' within anchor tag

Tags: angularjs

I want to show different tooltip messages based on certain conditions. I have written the below code for the same -

```
                     <a
                         ng-show="isManagedMeetingMandatory"
                         class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"
                         target="_blank"
                         ng-href="{{dynamicUrl}}"
                         uib-tooltip-html="'{{dynamicMsg}}'"
                         tooltip-placement="right"
                         tooltip-append-to-body="true">
                     </a>
```

The URL values changes as the javascript code but the message does not. Both of these variables are in the $scope variable.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe try removing ' uib-tooltip-html="{{dynamicMsg}}"

Answer (score 0):

Try this without single quotes and curly braces

```
 <a ng-show="isManagedMeetingMandatory"
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"
    target="_blank"
    ng-href="{{dynamicUrl}}"
    uib-tooltip-html="dynamicMsg"
    tooltip-placement="right"
    tooltip-append-to-body="true">
    </a>
```

Comment: No, the single braces dont seem to be the problem. I get the default value even with single braces. It is only the change in values og dynamicUrl which are not reflecting.